# ResumeThread takes over a minute to resume

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

I'm using `SuspendThread` / `ResumeThread` to modify the RIP register between the calls through `GetThreadContext` / `SetThreadContext`. It allows me to execute arbitrary code in a thread in another process.

So this works, but sometimes `ResumeThread` takes about 60 seconds to resume the target thread.

I understand that I'm somewhat abusing the API through this usage, but is there any way to speed this up? Or something I should look at that might indicate a bad usage?

The target thread is a sample program that loops over itself.

```
uint64_t blarg = 1;
while (true) {
    Sleep(100);
    std::cout << blarg << std::endl;
    blarg++;
    if (blarg == std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()) {
        blarg = 0;
    }
}
```

The Suspend / Resume sequence is very simple as well:

```
void hijackRip(uint64_t targetAddress, DWORD threadId){
    HANDLE targetThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, threadId);

    NTSTATUS suspendResult = SuspendThread(targetThread);
    CONTEXT threadContext;
    memset(&threadContext, 0, sizeof(threadContext));
    threadContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;
    BOOL getThreadContextResult = GetThreadContext(targetThread, &threadContext);
    threadContext.Rip = targetAddress;
    BOOL setThreadContextResult = SetThreadContext(targetThread, &threadContext);
    DWORD resumeThreadResult = ResumeThread(targetThread);
}
```

Again, this works, I can redirect execution correctly, but only 30 / 60 seconds after executing this function.

Comment: Have you tried doing SuspendThread from thread itself? I.e. sending some signal to thread and process that signal inside thread itself and suspending itself. Because if you suspend thread from other thread there might be racing conditions (locks, etc.) and threads may stall for long time while suspending.

Comment: Nice catch. The time to resume varies depending on the selected thread. I normally try to use the threads in reverse order of enumeration to avoid blocking the main thread for too long. However that seems to be "doubly" wrong as the threads are enumerated in reverse order already and the highest number one is the main thread. Anyway, I'll keep experimenting in that direction. Thanks

Comment: *Again, this works* - this code incorrect by design. and must not be used. simply change *Rip* at arbitrary point is wrong. you need something absolute another. what at all sense in this code ?

Comment: Are you implementing code injection? And consider using this api [`CreateRemoteThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread)

Comment: @RbMm By incorrect, you mean that it doesn't follow the x64 guidelines to modify RIP manually. By working, I mean that the x64 architecture can be setup in a way that will be indistinguishable from correct by the processor during execution.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Yes, it is what I'm doing. I'm trying to avoid the `CreateRemoteThread` call since it makes the injection easier to detect and prevent. I am not entirely certain of why it is inferior, but I would guess that CreateRemoteThread is almost always bad while the method at hand is harder to categorize at such a high degree of reliability. That, or simply CreateRemoteThread has been abused so much that everyone knows about it.

Comment: @Eric - what you doing - this is always UB by fact. modify context of thread at random point. in arbitrary state. thread for example can allocate memory from heap, when you change Eip/Rip and heap can be in inconsistent state at this point. as result allocate/free from this heap fail. thread can be inside some SRW lock, which is not recursive and if than you again try acquire this lock - you hang. many can be.. this way some time can "work" and some time fail. this never will be 100% stable work

Comment: and if thread wait on some objects or sleep (very possible variant) - it not break wait/sleep after you change eip/rip.